# Yet another "Why was my edit rejected?" question

Tags: discussion, suggested-edits, rejected-edits

I had been a fairly passive user of SO and only recently started to use it frequently. Now I actively try to keep the community clean by editing questions and providing constructive criticisms.

I was editing [this](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/32623185/revisions) question, but my edit was rejected and an edit that, in my opinion, violates the norms of [how codes should be edited in a question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260245/when-should-i-make-edits-to-code), was approved. The new editor has changed the code of the original question such that it fixes bugs in the actual question. I thought we were not supposed to do that! Or have I still not got the hang of editing?

For the record, here is the screenshot of the edit in question:

> Rejected Edit

[image]

> Approved Edit

[image]

Comment: The user appears to have edited their answer into the question. I've notified them of this post in a comment on the question.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

Ok, as the user who rejected the edit, here's a few points, not all totally correct but which I have corrected:

- First line of edit is removal of 'in Tcl' and I am one of those who don't like to see 'in XXX' (where XXX is a language), and most particularly on Questions with only one tag. The single tag should make it obvious that the problem is within that particular tag's context.
- Second line of edit: Indentation is good... but *that* particular indentation makes the code fail.

  ```
  for { set i 0} {$i<5} {incr i}
  {
      if { $node($i) < $node($i++)  }
      {
          puts "first $i"
      }
  }
  ```

  Running this piece of code would give the error:

  > wrong # args: should be "for start test next command"

  ... which means that this particular edit was not correct; thus my (now fixed) edit:

  ```
  for { set i 0} {$i<5} {incr i} {
      if { $node($i) < $node($i++)  } {
          puts "first $i"
      }
  }
  ```
- And the rest is some aesthetical edits with the spaces and lettercases which were correct in the edit.

Comment: I'd be glad to know what wrong there was, from the downvoters, so that I can be a better editor next time.

Comment: The 'the rejected edit made the code invalid' reason is absolutely valid for rejecting it.  I don't whole-heartedly agree with removing the language from the title, but that's a minor issue.